# Problem on characteristic polynomial of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Without computing $\det(xI-A)$, how to find the characteristic polynomial of $A$ where $A$ is a $4 \times 4$ matrix given by:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & -4 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/ Anyway, I think that may be a *companion matrix*...

Comment: That **is** a companion matrix: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix

Answer (score 1):

To compute the characteristic polynomial one generally use the [Faddeev-LeVerrier algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faddeev%E2%80%93LeVerrier_algorithm)

---

In your peculiar case however, your matrix has the form of a [**companion matrix**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix):

$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&\dots &0&-c_{0}\\1&0&\dots &0&-c_{1}\\0&1&\dots &0&-c_{2}\\\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots &\vdots \\0&0&\dots &1&-c_{{n-1}}\end{bmatrix}
$$

and by identification the characteristic polynomial is
$$
P(\lambda)=\sum_{k=0}^m c_k \lambda^k=4-5\lambda^2+\lambda^4
$$

---

In the general case if you want to play the game of not using $\det(\lambda I -A)$ you can use the Jacobi formula which can be obtained by "unfoding" the recurrence relation of the Faddeev-LeVerrier algorithm:

For a $A$ a $n\times n$ matrix, you have
$$
c_{n-m}={\frac {(-1)^{m}}{m!}}{\begin{vmatrix}\text{tr} A&m-1&0&\cdots \\\ \text{tr} A^{2}&\text{tr} A&m-2&\cdots \\\ \vdots &\vdots &&&\vdots \\\ \text {tr} A^{m-1}&\operatorname {tr} A^{m-2}&\cdots &\cdots &1\\\ \text {tr} A^{m}&\operatorname {tr} A^{m-1}&\cdots &\cdots &\operatorname {tr} A\end{vmatrix}}
$$

However there are a lot of computations and **it is easier to directly compute $\det(\lambda I -A)$**.

Anyway, here is the details for your example:
$$
A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & -4 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 5 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

- $m=0$ you have $c_4=1$ (the domimant coefficient of the polynomial is always $1$)
- $m=1$, $\text{tr}(A)=0$, hence $c_{4-1}=c_3=0$
- $m=2$, $\text{tr}(A^2)=10$
  $$
  c_{4-2}=\frac{(-1)^2}{2!}\left|
  \begin{array}{cc}
  0 & 2-1 \\ 10 & 0
  \end{array}
  \right|=\frac{1}{2}(-10)=-5
  $$
- $m=3$, $\text{tr}(A^3)=0$
  $$
  c_{4-3}=\frac{(-1)^3}{3!}\left|
  \begin{array}{ccc}
  0 & 3-1 & 0 \\ 10 & 0 & 3-2 \\
  0 & 10 & 0
  \end{array}
  \right|=\frac{-1}{6}(0)=0
  $$
- $m=4$, $\text{tr}(A^4)=34$
  $$
  c_{4-4}=\frac{(-1)^4}{4!}\left|
  \begin{array}{cccc}
  0  & 4-1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
  10 & 0   & 4-2 & 0 \\
  0  & 10  & 0 & 4-3 \\
  34 & 0 & 10 & 0 \\
  \end{array}
  \right|=\frac{1}{24}(96)=4
  $$

Your characteristic polynomial is
$$
P(\lambda)=4-5\lambda^2+\lambda^4
$$

which is hopefully the same answer as the "companion matrix" identification trick.

Comment: Probably overkill in this example.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown yes, however I m writing a more compact & detailed example using the Jacobi formula, hold on